# NSIS Call PowerShell in Uninstall Section

Tags: powershell, nsis, uninstallation

I'm working on creating a NSIS installer for our new VPN we will be getting in around a month.  I have it calling a PowerShell script to create the connection without issue.  However, removing the VPN connection is not working with the same method.  Below is all my code for the uninstall

```
Section Uninstall
  ExpandEnvStrings $0 "%COMSPEC%"
  ExecShell "" '"$0"' "/C powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -WindowStyle Hidden -File .\DeleteVPNConnection.ps1 -connectionName ${VPN_NAME} " SW_HIDE
  Delete "$INSTDIR\uninst.exe"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\CreateVPNConnection.ps1"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\DeleteVPNConnection.ps1"
  RMDir /r "$INSTDIR"
  DeleteRegKey ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}"
  SetAutoClose true
SectionEnd
```

Does anyone have any ideas why the uninstall script isn't working (and I have tried removing the connectionName parameter as well, same issue).

Comment: You are specifying ``.\`` for the script's path. What is the current directory when the `ExecShell` runs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

- You are specifying a relative .ps file path.
- `ExecShell` does not wait so the .ps file might get deleted too early.

If you are using NSIS 3.02 you can use `ExecShellWait`:

```
ExpandEnvStrings $0 "%COMSPEC%"
ExecShellWait "" '"$0"' '/C powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -WindowStyle Hidden -File "$InstDir\DeleteVPNConnection.ps1" -connectionName ${VPN_NAME}' SW_HIDE
```

If you are using a older NSIS version then you must use `ExecWait` (does not hide the console window) or the [nsExec plug-in](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/nsExec/nsExec.txt).